# Unlocking Moto G to homescreen

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I swipe to unlock my Moto G and it goes to phone book and not home screen. How can I make it go to home screen?

Answer (score 0):

Swipe up. You're used to swiping from the left to right to unlock from pre-Lollipop. The Lollipop home screen lets you swipe from left to right to unlock to the phone, right to left to unlock to the camera, or up from anywhere to just unlock.